# PayPal PHP REST API: Payment review has no effect in sandbox testing

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am developing a payment solution using the PayPal PHP REST SDK. Everything seems to work OK in the sandbox. I can make payments, and all the transactions show up on the dummy accounts for the seller and the buyer.

Now, I want to test with Payment Review, and have enabled this for one of my test users. According to this documentation

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_payment-review/

all transactions initiated by this user, should be set to "pending", but this doesn't happen. Alle transactions go through as normal. I've tried setting the seller account to payment review as well, but also with no effect.

Another issue is that none of the transactions appear under "Sandbox transactions", even though they appear in the respective paypal accounts of the dummy seller and buyers.

Is there something here I'm missing, or are these features just not working for the REST api?

Comment: Same here, Payment Review is OFF but all transactions are Completed and API calls on developer panel is empty.